boundary term in the integration by parts formula for difference quotient
I have a sequence of values in $\mathbb{R}$ say $f_{k}$ where $k\in{0,1,\ldots, N}$ and a step $h=\frac{T}{N}$. Then I define the piecewise constant function
\begin{align}
f_{h}(x)=f_{k}\mbox{ for all }x\in((k-1)h,kh].
\end{align}
For any test function $\phi\in C_{0}^{\infty}([0,T))$ which means this function is compactly supported in $[0,T)$ and $\phi(0)$ can take non-zero value, I am considering the following integral
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}\frac{f_{h}(t)-f_{h}(t-h)}{h}\phi(t) dt.
\end{align}
My question is that if I assume that $f_{h}\to f$ weakly in $L^{2}$, can I have
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{T}\frac{f_{h}(t)-f_{h}(t-h)}{h}\phi(t) dt\to f(0)\phi(0)-\int_{0}^{T}f(t)\phi^{\prime}(t)dt?
\end{align}
My thought is to use the "integration by parts" formula for the difference quotient, then since $\phi$ is a good function, we can pass to the limit, but my problem is how do we get the boundary term?

Using the coordinate transform $t-h \mapsto t$ in the second half of the integrand, we get
$$
\int_0^T \frac1h( f_h(t) - f_h(t-h)) \phi(t)dt
= \int_0^T \frac1h  f_h(t) \phi(t)dt
- \int_{-h}^{T-h} \frac1h  f_h(t) \phi(z+h)dt \\
= \int_0^T \frac1h  f_h(t) \phi(t)dt
- \int_{-h}^{T} \frac1h  f_h(t) \phi(z+h)dt \\
= \int_0^T \frac1h  f_h(t) (\phi(t)-\phi(z+h))dt
- \int_{-h}^0 \frac1h  f_h(t) \phi(z+h)dt .
$$
Since $\phi$ is smooth, we have
$$
\frac1h ( \phi(t) - \phi(t+h))  \to -\phi'(t),
$$
moreover this convergence is uniform. Then we can pass to the limit in the first integral to obtain
$$
\int_0^T \frac1h( f_h(t) - f_h(t-h)) \phi(t)dt \to - \int_0^1 f(t) \phi'(t)dt = - \int_0^T f(t) \phi'(t)dt .
$$
We cannot say anything about
$$
 \int_{-h}^0 \frac1h  f_h(t) \phi(z+h)dt,
$$
as you did not define $f_h$ on $(-h,0)$.
